# How to create table with binary values based on existing some values in two other tables in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have two tables in Teradata SQL like below:

**Table1**:

| ID |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |

**Table2**:

| ID |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |

Based on two tables above I need to create one table like below.
So:

- col: tab1 --> If ID is in table 1 give them 1 and 0 otherwise.
- col: tab2 --> If ID is in table 2 give them 1 and 0 otherwise.

**Desired result**:

| ID | tab1 | tab2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 | 0 |
| 12 | 1 | 0 |
| 13 | 0 | 1 |
| 14 | 0 | 1 |
| 15 | 0 | 1 |

How can I do that in Teradata SQL ?

Comment: What do you mean by "binary values"? Teradata doesn't have any type named "binary" (and surprisingly it doesn't have a `bool` / Boolean / `bit` type either...), the smallest type is `BYTEINT`: https://docs.teradata.com/r/iRq_F~XxKYWu7Kv~HRd~ew/D_RBrANpKte9E5uvWjq8~Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Teradata seems to support enough of ISO SQL-2003 natively](https://docs.teradata.com/r/iRq_F%7EXxKYWu7Kv%7EHRd%7Eew/tOAp1v0iH%7EpdKSJmCns7Fg), so no Teradata-specific SQL extensions or proprietary features is needed (i.e. the exact same query will work in MSSQL Server, Oracle, MariaDB, etc).

You'll want a `UNION` of `table1` and `table2`'s values and then JOINed back, which is straightforward:

```
WITH distinctIdValues AS (
    SELECT id FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT id FROM table2
)
SELECT
    dv.id,
    CASE WHEN t1.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS tab1,
    CASE WHEN t2.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS tab2
FROM
    distinctIdValues AS dv
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 AS t1 ON dv.id = t1.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON dv.id = t2.id
```

You can then use this query either as a `VIEW` or materialize it into a new `TABLE`:

```
CREATE VIEW foobar AS /* same SQL as above */;

SELECT * FROM foobar;
```

Teradata's documentation is unclear about how/if [a CTE](https://docs.teradata.com/r/b8dd8xEYJnxfsq4uFRrHQQ/UVfLexchvgigqg8rPUBymg) can be used with an `INSERT` statement, so I'll use an inner-query instead:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (
    id   int     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    tab1 byteint NOT NULL,
    tab2 byteint NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO foobar ( id, tab1, tab2 )
SELECT
    dv.id,
    CASE WHEN t1.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS tab1,
    CASE WHEN t2.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS tab2
FROM
    (
        SELECT id FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT id FROM table2
    )
        AS dv
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 AS t1 ON dv.id = t1.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON dv.id = t2.id
ORDER BY
    dv.id
;
```

---

**Or just this:**

Props to @dnoeth for reminding me that it can be reduced to this:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE( t1.id, t2.id ) AS id,
    CASE WHEN t1.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS tab1,
    CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS tab2
FROM
    table1 AS t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY
    COALESCE( t1.id, t2.id )
```

Comment: No need for a complex Select, just use a Full Outer Join :-)

Comment: @dnoeth \*headdesk\*

Comment: @dnoeth I think I subconscously avoid `FULL OUTER JOIN` because so many RDBMS still don't support it natively (e.g. MySQL) - not that I'd ever admit to using MySQL in any professional capacity, of course

Comment: @dnoeth I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a Full Outer Join:

```
SELECT
   Coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) AS id
  ,CASE WHEN t1.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS tab1
  ,CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS tab2
FROM table1 AS t1 
FULL JOIN table2 AS t2 
  ON t1.id = t1.id
```